# Cannot make RemoteServiceRelativePath and XML work (GWT)

Tags: xml, gwt, xml-rpc, rpc

I think I have a bad configuration of my XML files for my GTW project because when I try to contact the remote service I get this error: "**Problem accessing /myresults/compress. Reason: NOT_FOUND**". Please find below the important pieces of my code if anyone can help me, I think it is related to RemoteServiceRelativePath and my XML.

**UPDATE:** When I change in web.xml the content of URL-PATTERN I still get exactly the same message with path /myresults/compress.

**CompressionService.java**

```
package myProject.client;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;
/* The client side stub for the RPC service. */
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("compress")
public interface CompressionService extends RemoteService {
    String compress(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

**CompressionServiceImpl.java**

```
package myProject.server;
import myProject.client.CompressionService;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
/* The server side implementation of the RPC service. */
public class CompressionServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        CompressionService {
    public String compress(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        String output = "aaaa";
        return output;
    }
}
```

**CompressionService.java**

```
package myProject.client;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
/* The async counterpart of <code>CompressService</code> */
public interface CompressionServiceAsync {
    void compress(String input, AsyncCallback<String> callback)
            throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>compressionService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myProject.server.CompressionServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>compressionService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myresults/compress</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>MyResults.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**MyResults.gwt.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='myresults'>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
  <entry-point class='myProject.client.MyResults'/>
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>
</module>
```

**MyResults.java**

```
private final CompressionServiceAsync compressionService = GWT.create(CompressionService.class);
compressionService.compress(text, new AsyncCallback<String>() {
              public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                // Show the RPC error message to the user
                download.setText(caught.getMessage()));             
              }
              public void onSuccess(String result) {
                download.setText(result);
              }
});
```

Comment: I had this problem. In my case the web server was using wrong `web.xml` and not the one treated with [gwt-maven-plugin:mergewebxml](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/remoteservicerelativepath-annotation.html) maven goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are already thinking on the right lines. The problem seems to be that your `@RemoteServiceRelativePath` and web.xml `url-mapping` doesn't agree with each other.

Probably changing servlet-mapping in web.xml to following will fix your problem:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>compressionService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/compress</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Tahir. I will test it in 3 hours... but I thought URL-PATTERN content should be the text of MODULE-RENAME-TO / RELATIVE PATH. That is why I have /myresults/compress. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hi, I have tested it and it is strange. I can write anything in url-pattern but the error message "Problem accessing /myresults/compress. Reason: NOT_FOUND" is exactly the same. I have cleaned, recompiled, even deleted web.xml and created it again, but I have the same result. What is happening??? THANKS

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of the exception? What url are you using to access your gwt page?

Comment: Also try doing `GWT.alert(GWT.getModuleBasePath())` in your code somewhere.

Comment: New update Tahir. I have deployed it in Google App Engine and it works! But in my local server it does not configured in eclipse it does not. I access http://127.0.0.1/MyResults.html. I have set URL-PATTERN back to /encodingresults/compress. Any guess why does it happen locally? THANKS

Comment: Surprinsingly now it is working after restoring web.xml. Thank you Tahir!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue where the servlet path from web.xml was not updated in the application even after deleting all GWT generated files and browser history.
Even more strangely, the issue appeared only on Chrome but not on Firefox.

Turns out that Chrome was still loading the old version of web.xml from GWT temporary directory which is displayed at system start-up:
*Super Dev Mode starting up
workDir: C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-3864057753329430362.tmp*

After removing the data from this temporary directory as well, the application was updated in Chrome too.